# retURL is not working

Tags: apex

I have a VF page and it is associated with standard controller. On the page, I am using **apex:detail** tag to bring all the details. I also want to show few related list, So I used **apex:relatedlist**. This all works fine. The only thing which is problemtic is when I click on "New" button on related-list to create a new record after saving the record it doesn't bring me back to the original VF page, instead it takes me to the detail-page of related-list record. Any thoughts what wrong I am doing?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:pageBlock>
You're looking at some related lists for {!account.name}:</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />

<apex:relatedList list="Contacts">
    <apex:facet name="header">Titles can be overriden with facets</apex:facet>
</apex:relatedList>

<apex:relatedList list="Cases" title="Or you can keep the image, but change the text" />
```

Comment: I think this is the standard behaviour.You may overwrite standard Save button to change the navigation back to parent view .

Comment: Does this mean I have to create another VF page for creating New Record and inside controller I will have to override save?

Comment: Ya that can be done as well.But you can override save action as well .Override the Save Action

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before in a slightly different way, but the answers and sample code I believe still apply. Check out, [Redirecting back to original page using visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/redirecting-back-to-original-page-using-visualforce).

Comment: Intrestingly both the questions are by the same user :X!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using standard controller, your save will behave the way it behaves when you save a record. And the problem here is, you cant override your Save button. You'll need to create a vf page and implement the save in your controller for that page.